# SQLite exception in Jelly bean but not in marshmallow

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I upgraded my app to marshmallow and getting sqlite database full exception.
The db code is,

```
package com.app;

import java.io.File;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class Sqlitedb extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABASE="appname";
private static final int VERSION=8;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TODO = "CREATE TABLE user (" + "id" + " INTEGER," + "value" + " INTEGER" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TODO1 = "CREATE TABLE trend (id INTEGER,url TEXT,image TEXT,title TEXT,count INTEGER,height TEXT,width  TEXT,points  INTEGER,sourceavail TEXT)";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TODO2 = "CREATE TABLE random (id INTEGER,url TEXT,image TEXT,title TEXT,count INTEGER,height TEXT,width  TEXT,points  INTEGER,sourceavail TEXT)";

public Sqlitedb(final Context context) 
 {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Appname"
                + File.separator + DATABASE  , null, VERSION);

 }

public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String dbfile,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) 
{
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO1);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO2);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{


    if(oldVersion < 7)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user");
        onCreate(db);           
    }

    if(newVersion == 8){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO1);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO2);
    }

}

public Cursor getDetails(String table) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM  "+table+" order by id desc";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return c;
}
public Cursor getDetails(String table,Integer integer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM  "+table+" where id='"+integer+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return c;
}

public void deleteData(String table) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(table, null, null);
}
```

}

From MainPage,

```
Sqlitedb db = new Sqlitedb(getActivity());
Cursor c = db.getDetails("trend");
```

The tables are created in Marshmallow but not in Jelly bean. The database is created as i can access sqlite_master and android_metadata tables. Tried by adding  getWritableDatabase(); to the constructor of Sqlitedb.
looks like onCreate is not executed.

**Strack Trace:**

```
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteFullException: database or disk is full (code 13)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:552)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:437)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:522)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:263)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at com.app.db.Sqlitedb.getDetails(Sqlitedb.java:188)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at com.app.TrendActivity.onCreateView(TrendActivity.java:119)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
09-14 08:44:53.890: E/AndroidRuntime(25054):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
```

It is working fine in Marshmallow added with realtime permission request.
Please help.

Comment: please check this one https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/664

Comment: Just to be sure, you also have permission in manifest?

Comment: @MikeT :  yes permission in place. we just upgraded to 23 and added marshmallow ondemand permission request in the application start. No changes have been done to the sqliteDB. The behavior difference is strange here.

Comment: Perhaps post changes made to request permission, or revert change to see if that fixes issue.

Comment: No if i revert back 6.0 support will be lost.

Comment: I know it is a bit late, but I have encountered a similar error when the initial load of the application had a hiccup during the database population. I resolved it by completely removing and reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 0):

From SQLite documentation

(13) SQLITE_FULL

The SQLITE_FULL result code indicates that a write could not complete because the disk is full. Note that this error can occur when trying to write information into the main database file, or it can also occur when writing into temporary disk files. Sometimes applications encounter this error even though there is an abundance of primary disk space because the error occurs when writing into temporary disk files on a system where temporary files are stored on a separate partition with much less space that the primary disk. https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#full

I guess application is installed on SDCARD or someth

> If your disk is full. You ran out of disk space

Comment: application is installed on internal sd card having enough space. What is the possible fix?

Comment: SDK is the latestt version 23.

Comment: @Vignesh I do not think you can install the app on a sd card based on version I would do a search about what version Android stopped this concept

Comment: @Vector Android never "stopped this concept" and has actually made significant progress in expanding it. I would assume from your statement that you have not had any experience in Android. If the disk being full is the issue, it may be that the database is one of the items that is still kept in internal data for security reasons.

Comment: @AbandonedCart I can install apps on the SD Card but everytime I try to install an app with SQLite the SD card complains that it is full tested with new SD card so how do we solve the issue

Comment: @Vector As I said before, it's possible that the database is not being installed on the sdcard with your app and the storage limits of the **device** are the ones being applied. Have you tried having the database installed to external storage?

Comment: @AbandonedCart Yes we direct android to install on the SD card new and old with small amount of data It was my thought that the app could not be installed on the SD card ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to say. Are you installing the **app** on the sdcard or creating the **database** on the sdcard? If you are installing the **app**, then you should try having the **database** created on the sdcard. If you are creating the **database** on the sdcard, then you should verify the default creation works before trying to create it elsewhere.

Comment: Per https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location, "The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device memory."